# Google Drive SDK - Php Client Library - Download a file where i can find the classes?

Tags: google-drive-api

I try to download a file using this method

```
/**
 * Download a file's content.
 *
 * @param Google_DriveService $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param File $file Drive File instance.
 * @return String The file's content if successful, null otherwise.
 */
function downloadFile($service, $file) {
  $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
}
```

found there : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

But i don't know where in the library i can find those two classes that i need to include :

> - **Google_HttpRequest**
> - **Google_Client**

Library: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fio

and

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%253Fstate%253Dclosed